# Correct way to have two columns, one float left and one float right

Tags: css, xpages

I have struggled with this in web and Xpages programming.

I want a container that is responsive, and a table with two columns. In the left column I want my label or field to be flush left and on the right flush right.

I believe I should not use a table, but divs.

The code I have tried is as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style type="text/css">


.container {
width: auto;
}

.left {
float:left;
}

.right {
float:right;    
}

.line {
display:inline;
}

</style>
</head>
<div class = "container">

<div class = "line"><p class="left">Label 1</p><p class = "right">Value 1</div>

<div class = "line">Label 2</div>
<div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Bear in mind Internet Explorer compatibility mode (which can be forced for internal sites) ignores float.

Answer (score 0):

I almost always prefer setting up two container `<div>` and setting them both to

```
   display: inline-block;
```

so for your example something like:

```
   .line{ display:inline-block;width:50%;} /* or 48% depending if there are margins etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to create two columns that bump up against one another, you don't need your "right" style to float:right.  You actually want it to float:left so that it falls inline right next to your left column.

Also, your container div does not have a closing tag and your right column p tag is not closed.  Label2 is in the div as opposed to a p tag as in the first row.

When you float objects, often you need to "clear" them.  I've taken your code and modified to demonstrate what I think you are trying to accomplish:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<style type="text/css">


.container {
width: auto;
padding:10px;
background:#eee;
}

.left {
 float:left;
 width:45%; 
}

.right {
 float:left; 
 width:45%;  
}
.clear {
    clear:both; 
}

.line {
border:1px solid #000;
margin:10px 0;
background:#fff;
}

</style>

<div class = "container">

    <div class = "line">
        <p class="left">Label 1</p>
        <p class = "right">Value 1</p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class = "line">
        <p class="left">Label 2</p>
        <p class = "right">Value 2</p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</xp:view>
```